# Can Url Rewrite only rewrite to an internal url?

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting, sharepoint-2010

I've installed IIS 7.0 with SharePoint and Url Rewrite module.

Are the following sentences or perhaps I have configured something incorrectly to see this result?

Url Redirect can redirect a url to any internal (on the same site) or external urls (on a separate site).

Url Rewrite can only rewrite to an internal url?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Url Rewrite can redirect a url to any internal (on the same site) or external urls (on a separate site).

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to be true to me. test this; try rewrite http://www.google.com into a site url of yours e.g. http://mysite/mypage.aspx.

Comment: Ok, let's rephrase that: Url Rewrite can redirect any URL mapped to the current host to any internal (on the same site) or external urls (on a separate site). So mapping Google.com will not work (because it is Google's domain, not yours).

Comment: Url redirecting is fine. Url rewriting to external sites doesn't work. I was advised that I'd need to configure reverse proxy with url rewriting to make it work: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: URL Rewrite in itself cannot rewrite to any other site or application that is not running on the same Application Pool. In other words it not only have to be in the same machine, but also in the same AppPool. HAVING SAID THAT when you install Application Request Routing, then it will work rewriting to remote servers (regardless where or what they are) since the Routing will take care of that. So just install ARR and enable Proxy.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. yeah, I've installed ARR and enabled Proxy. I've enabled windows authentication for both sites but the rewriting doesn't work. Having said that when anonymous access is enabled url rewriting works. How can I make windows authentication work with url rewriting?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually rewrite to a different server (so your domain displays content loaded from an external site) using ARR (Application Request Routing) with reverse proxy rules. Here's a step by step guide on how to do it and keep your relative paths working:

http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr